# how to fix this warnning?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

```
$ nautilus

(nautilus:2658): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
(nautilus:2658): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
(nautilus:2658): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(nautilus:2658): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(nautilus:2658): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Comment: Does this stop it from working?

Comment: No, it doesn't stop

Comment: Then ignore it!